# Django is loading template from the wrong app

Tags: python, django

I have a view under my elearning app named home(), which should load index.html from within the app's directory. Instead it loads an instance of index.html from a different app (symposium/templates/index.html). It should be loading it from (elearning/templates/index.html).

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
# Settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        # Machina dependencies:
    'mptt',
    'haystack',
    'widget_tweaks',

    # Machina apps:
    'machina',
    'machina.apps.forum',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation.forum_attachments',
    'machina.apps.forum_conversation.forum_polls',
    'machina.apps.forum_feeds',
    'machina.apps.forum_moderation',
    'machina.apps.forum_search',
    'machina.apps.forum_tracking',
    'machina.apps.forum_member',
    'machina.apps.forum_permission',
    # SCORM apps:
    'accounts',
    'symposium',
    'elearning']

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'), MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'machina.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

```
# root urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from machina import urls as machina_urls
from accounts.views import CreateUser
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('forum/',include(machina_urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('createuser',CreateUser.as_view()),
    path('symposium/', include('symposium.urls')),
    path('elearning/', include('elearning.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

```
# elearning app urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

app_name = 'elearning'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

```
# app: elearning/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'index.html',{})
```

```
# index.html location
elearning templates : ./elearning/templates/index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django searches for a templates folder within each app for the relevant template to render. Looks like the first it found was `index.html` from within the `symposium` app.

The convention of directory structure for templates is to put your templates within another folder with the name of the app in order to avoid this exact situation with templates of the same name.

Move your `index.html` file from

`/elearning/templates/index.html`

to

`/elearning/templates/elearning/index.html`

and then change your home view function to

```py
def home(request):
    return render(request,'elearning/index.html',{})
```

and similarly do the same for the location of the `index.html` file in the `symposium` app.